# Attribute error in python with Google Speech API

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

'str' object has no attribute 'long_running_recognize'.  This error is occurring at the last line of the code shown.  I jump into the code and see no obvious reason for it to fail.  Jumps out at the wrap_method below.

```
if "long_running_recognize" not in self._inner_api_calls:
   self._inner_api_calls[
        "long_running_recognize"
        ] = google.api_core.gapic_v1.method.wrap_method(
            self.transport.long_running_recognize,
default_retry=self._method_configs["LongRunningRecognize"].retry,           
     default_timeout=self._method_configs["LongRunningRecognize"].timeout,
            client_info=self._client_info,
        )
```

The only issue that I could conceive here is maybe the audio file is too large(45mb...53 min).  But the code break happens in a location that doesn't appear to relate to this.

```
import io
import os

from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

with open("path\\My First Project-edb18653fedf.json") as f:
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = f.read()

client = speech.SpeechClient(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
file_path = "audio\\102.flac"

with io.open(file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
     content = audio_file.read()

     audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    sample_rate_hertz=32000,
    language_code='en-US')

operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)


Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7479.30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1758, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1147, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/shear/Documents/PythonScripts/GStTEnv/SpeechToText/CloudSpeechText.py", line 105, in <module>
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
  File "C:\Users\shear\GStTEnv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\gapic\speech_client.py", line 314, in long_running_recognize
    self.transport.long_running_recognize,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'long_running_recognize'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to prove out your theory about the length of the audio?  What happens if you trim the audio and try it?

Does it happen if you try a curl request at the command line instead of code?

I’d like to see if I can help.  To diagnose further, would you be able to provide:
- Exact steps to reproduce
- Pointer to github repo if available
- As much of the code as you can provide
- Exact error messages
- Language Code (config)
- All configuration options applicable
- Sample audio file with all personal data removed (on Google Drive or Cloud Storage)

Comment: I shortened the Audio file to 5 minutes and experience the same error.  Tried the same code at the command line and same error.  Working on learning about a curl request to try this method.  Digging through the debugger makes it appear that the error is a direct result of the example code provided at https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize.  The library install and setup is here https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries.  I will send the sample file your way via email.  I am using PyCharm to debug the code.

Comment: I thought I would try to trace the error.  However, I can't find speech_client.py anywhere on github.  Perhaps removing and re-installing the python client library might help you?

Comment: I suggest you look at speech_client.py", line 314 and follow where it leads you

Comment: You need to install the python library via 'pip install -update google-cloud-speech".  Then you should be able to trace down speech_client.py.

Comment: Line 314 is precisely where it breaks. My problem is that I cannot determine the root cause of the break. The purpose of the method at the break is to wrap some attributes around the class, but it says that there is no string that should be present.  I have inspected the code here during the instance, I do not know the source of where this string should come from and therefore am puzzled as to why it is missing or how to reconcile the problem. It seems at the very least that the code may need to be modified to catch this exception and perhaps explain the source of the problem.